# Consulta com condições usando aggregate MongoDB + nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, restful, mongoose

Eu tenho um código que me retorna arrays com os parâmetros que eu preciso para alimentar minha página HTML, porém, eu preciso incluir algumas condições nessa busca para que ele pegue apenas os valores após uma determinada data.

```
var obj = await Hist.aggregate([{$group: {
        _id:'$pagform', 
        contagem:{$sum:1}, 
        soma:{$sum:'$valor'}
    }}])
    labels = []
    contagem = []
    soma=[]
    obj.forEach(x => {
        labels.push(x._id),
        contagem.push(x.contagem)
        soma.push(x.soma)
    });
    res.json({labels, contagem, soma})
```

Seria um código similar ao find(), porem que me retornasse um json com os mesmos arrays que a consulta usando o aggregate, por exemplo:

```
var all = await Hist.find({hora_saida:{ $gt: '2020-02-01' }},{'pagform':1,'valor':1,'':1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entende como funciona os `pipelines` do `aggregate`?

Basicamente você está passando um array de comandos para serem executados no seu banco, o retorno de cada comando, é passado como entrada para o próximo.

No se código você tem o seguinte:

```
Hist.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$pagform', 
      contagem: { $sum: 1 }, 
      soma: { $sum: '$valor' }
    }
  }
])
```

Nesse código existe apenas um comando, `$group`, ele será executado sobre todos os documentos da sua collection `Hist`. Se você quer que ele só seja executado sobre os documentos cuja `hora_saida` seja superior a `2020-02-01`, você pode adicionar um comando para filtrar esses documentos antes de executar o `$group`:

```
Hist.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { 
      hora_saida: { $gt: '2020-02-01' }
    } 
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$pagform', 
      contagem: { $sum: 1 }, 
      soma: { $sum: '$valor' }
    }
  }
])
```

O retorno de `$match` serão os documentos com a data especificada, esses documentos servirão de entrada para o `$group`.

---

Em nota: a query que eu usei como exemplo só funcionaria se sua `hora_saida` estiver salva com o tipo `string`, o que provavelmente está errado. Se `hora_saida` for do tipo `Date`, você deveria utilizar `hora_saida: { $gt: new Date('2020-02-01') }`

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, ajudou demais, obrigado!!!